# Exclude quotation while ordering data from mysql in php

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, sql-order-by

Hi I have a php select statement that extracts everything from database and orders by starting letter of string. It takes quotations into account which i don't want. I want it to look at the next character after quotes and order it accordingly. I'm Open to JS solutions as long as they don't remove the quotes. Thanks

Comment: js solutions for php? Are you sure?

Comment: If you don't know or forgot somehow, here we need codes.

Comment: @u_mulder I mean once I get the data into a `<div>` then I use Javascript to maybe add it to an array and order it by replacing the quotation and adding them again later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was so simple. Add php echoed values to an array using split function then use sort function.

```
array.sort(function mysortfunction(a,b) {
  a = a.text.replace(/"/g,'');
  b = b.text.replace(/"/g,'');

  return (a < b ? -1 : 1);
});
```